# Determine appropriate number of Tasks

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I am working on a small library which uses the Task Parallel Library to run parallel searches for a solution. The current design works along these lines:

- a ConcurrentQueue receives the result of Searches,
- a main Task works as a loop, operating as a background thread. When a new Solution arrives to the Queue, it dequeues and processes it, and then launches a new Search on a new Task,
- a Search is launched in its own Task, and returns its result to the Queue once complete.

[Edit based on Eric J's answer: the activities involved are entirely CPU bound, there is no IO involved]

The framework works great as is for now. However, I have complete control over the number of Search tasks which will be triggered, and my understanding is that while the TPL handles the situation very well for the moment, shoving a large number of searches at the system will not result in increased parallelism because it will be bound by the number of cores available on the system, and will become counter-productive after a certain level.

My question is the following: can I "help" the TPL by limiting the number of Search tasks that will be run, and if yes, how would I go about determining what that upper-limit should be? Would it be appropriate to limit it based for instance on System.Environment.ProcessorCount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, unless there is a real performance problem here, I would just let the TPL do it's thing.  It is quite good at that.

If you do need to control the number of tasks to solve a real performance issue, you need to understand what is limiting performance.  Are your tasks CPU bound?  IO bound?  Are you running out of physical memory, causing swapping?

Once you know what the limiting factor is, you can certainly *monitor* that factor and adjust the number of running tasks based on that (runtime) measured value.  For example, if your tasks are CPU bound but have some IO time, hard limiting based on the # of cores is close but not optimal.  Limit instead based on overall CPU utilization.  *This assumes that the machine is mostly dedicated to processing this task.  If not, hand-tuning is significantly more complex and error prone.*

Comment: I should have specified - the problem is entirely CPU bound, there is no IO involved.

Comment: I did something very much like this with a CPU bound process.  Kept adding worker threads until overall CPU utilization reached a configurable amount CPU_THRESHOLD (70% worked well in my case).  If CPU got higher, didn't create any more worker threads until it got under say 0.9 * CPU_THRESHOLD, then allowed additional worker threads to be created.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I want to do - I would like to "auto-tune" the search to adapt to capacity. Naive question - how do you go about measuring/evaluating CPU utilization?

Comment: That is, can you measure CPU utilization from within your code as it is running?

Comment: For measuring your own CPU utilization, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275957/can-a-c-sharp-program-measure-its-own-cpu-usage-somehow