# ASP.NET Website Server Timing API does not display time info

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, server-timing

I have an ASP.NET Website. I am using the following code in Global.Asax.cs

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Context.Response.SetServerTiming(
    new ServerTimingMetric("cache", 300, "Cache"),
    new ServerTimingMetric("sql", 900, "Sql Server"),
    new ServerTimingMetric("fs", 600, "FileSystem"),
    new ServerTimingMetric("cpu", 1230, "Total CPU")
);

        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for HttpResponseHeadersExtensions
/// </summary>
public static class HttpResponseHeadersExtensions
{
    public static void SetServerTiming(this HttpResponse response, params ServerTimingMetric[] metrics)
    {
        ServerTimingHeaderValue serverTiming = new ServerTimingHeaderValue();

        foreach (ServerTimingMetric metric in metrics)
        {
            serverTiming.Metrics.Add(metric);
            response.Headers.Add("Server-Timing", serverTiming.ToString());
        }


        //response.Headers.Append("Server-Timing", serverTiming.ToString());
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for IServerTiming
/// </summary>
public interface IServerTiming
{
    ICollection<ServerTimingMetric> Metrics { get; }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

internal class ServerTiming : IServerTiming
{
    public ICollection<ServerTimingMetric> Metrics { get; }

    public ServerTiming()
    {
        Metrics = new List<ServerTimingMetric>();
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ServerTimingHeaderValue
{
    public ICollection<ServerTimingMetric> Metrics { get; }

    public ServerTimingHeaderValue()
    {
        Metrics = new List<ServerTimingMetric>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(",", Metrics);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Globalization;
using System;

public struct ServerTimingMetric
{
    private string _serverTimingMetric;

    public string Name { get; }

    public decimal? Value { get; }

    public string Description { get; }

    public ServerTimingMetric(string name, decimal? value, string description)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Description = description;

        _serverTimingMetric = null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_serverTimingMetric == null)
        {
            _serverTimingMetric = Name;

            if (Value.HasValue)
                _serverTimingMetric = _serverTimingMetric + "=" + Value.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
                _serverTimingMetric = _serverTimingMetric + ";\"" + Description + "\"";
        }
        return _serverTimingMetric;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following output,
[image]

Has anyone configured the Server Timing API for the old ASP.NET Website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sends out more than 1 `Server-Timing` HTTP header while there should only be 1.
The image you included shows 4 `cache` items in the lower left.

Also, the HTTP header value being sent out is not according to the [specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Server-Timing).
That is the reason why you only see `cache` (4 times) in your image; the other parts are not being recognized.

In order to get the result you are looking for, that single `Server-Timing` HTTP header must look like below.

```
Server-Timing: cache;desc="Cache";dur=300, sql;desc="Sql Server";dur=900, fs;desc="FileSystem";dur=600, cpu;desc="Total CPU";dur=1230
```

Each timing item has a name, e.g. `cache`, optionally followed by key value pairs separated by a semicolon, with `desc` for the description and `dur` for the duration. When a description (`desc`) is present and when it contains a space then it must be enclosed by double quotes.

An example: `sql;desc="Sql Server";dur=900`

---

With the correct header in place, my web browser (Chrome) shows below.

[image]

---

I made these changes.

1. In class `HttpResponseHeadersExtensions`, add only a single `Server-Timing` HTTP header.

```
public static class HttpResponseHeadersExtensions
{
    public static void SetServerTiming(this HttpResponse response, params ServerTimingMetric[] metrics)
    {
        ServerTimingHeaderValue serverTiming = new ServerTimingHeaderValue();

        foreach (ServerTimingMetric metric in metrics)
        {
            serverTiming.Metrics.Add(metric);
        }

        response.Headers.Add("Server-Timing", serverTiming.ToString());
    }
}
```

2. In struct `ServerTimingMetric`, format the string representation differently.

```
public struct ServerTimingMetric
{
    // Existing code left out for brevity.

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (_serverTimingMetric == null)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder(Name);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
                builder.AppendFormat(@";desc=""{0}""", Description);

            if (Value != null)
                builder.AppendFormat(@";dur=""{0}""", Value);

            _serverTimingMetric = builder.ToString();
        }

        return _serverTimingMetric;
    }
}
```

3. In class `ServerTimingHeaderValue`, join the metrics by a comma and space instead of only by a comma.

```
public class ServerTimingHeaderValue
{
    // Other code left out for brevity.

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(", ", Metrics);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! It is working for me now. Do you know how can I get the server time to report the actual CPU time? Right now, because I have `new ServerTimingMetric("cpu", 1230, "Total CPU")` this line it always reports CPU time as `1.23s`. How to calculate the actual CPU time for a particular request?

Comment: @tRuEsAtM That's beyond my knowledge and rather a topic/question on it's own. Maybe you can start from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275957/can-a-c-sharp-program-measure-its-own-cpu-usage-somehow) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c).